# Implementing Strahler Stream Order in Mathematica

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to implement the [Strahler stream order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strahler_number) in Mathematica.

I've found some [SQL code](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8z58LCVhD62YvkeJjriW8d/5) for it online.

And this is the code that I've written so far

```
streams = 
    Table[{node, to_node, expected_order}, {node, 1, 19}]

streams[[1]] = {1, Null, 4};
streams[[2]] = {2, 1, 4};
streams[[3]] = {3, 2, 3};
streams[[4]] = {4, 2, 3};
streams[[5]] = {5, 4, 3};
streams[[6]] = {6, 3, 2};
streams[[7]] = {7, 3, 2};
streams[[8]] = {8, 5, 2};
streams[[9]] = {9, 5, 2};
streams[[10]] = {10, 6, 1};
streams[[11]] = {11, 6, 1};
streams[[12]] = {12, 7, 1};
streams[[13]] = {13, 7, 1};
streams[[14]] = {14, 8, 1};
streams[[15]] = {15, 8, 1};
streams[[16]] = {16, 9, 1};
streams[[17]] = {17, 9, 1};
streams[[18]] = {18, 4, 1};
streams[[19]] = {19, 1, 1};

(* Define the Strahler function *)
strahler[parentNodeId] := Module[{childrenStrahlerOrders, maxStrahlerOrder, nodeStrahlerOrder},
  childrenStrahlerOrders = strahler[parentNodeId] /. Null -> 0;
  maxStrahlerOrder = Max[childrenStrahlerOrders];
  minStrahlerOrder = Min[childrenStrahlerOrders];
  nodeStrahlerOrder = If[Length[childrenStrahlerOrders] <= Length[streams], 1,
    If[minStrahlerOrder < maxStrahlerOrder, maxStrahlerOrder, maxStrahlerOrder + 1]];
  {nodeStrahlerOrder}
];

(* Calculate the Strahler orders *)
strahlerOrders = {};
  Do[
    If[Length[strahler[parentNodeId]] == 0,
      strahlerOrders = strahlerOrders + {0},
      strahlerOrders = strahlerOrders + {strahler[parentNodeId]}
    ],
    {parentNodeId, 1, Length[streams]}
  ]
```

But this doesn't seem to work! Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: This is implemented as `IGStrahlerNumber` in the IGraph/M package. See http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @Szabolcs do you know if there's any functionality for looking at the bifurcation ratio using IGStrahlerNumber/

Comment: Nevermind - wrote some code for it myself